# ¿Cómo consultar en un "if" si un comando se ejecuta sin errores?

Tags: bash, if, condiciones, shell-script

¿Cómo consultar en un "if" si un comando se ejecuta sin errores?

Por ejemplo en este código:

```
valor1=`find . -type f -name ./DATA*`
if [ valor1 = True]; then
    echo "funcionó sin problemas"
else
    echo "no funcionó"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe la variable `$?` que guarda el código de salida de un comando. Si se ejecuta correctamente devuelve 0; en caso contrario, un número diferente.

Por ello, puedes hacer:

```
comando
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "funcionó"
else
   echo "algo falló"
fi
```

Si no te importa el resultado del comando, puedes hacer directamente:

```
if comando; then
   echo "funcionó"
else
   echo "algo falló"
fi
```

Comment: El $? guardaría la salida de strerr o sólo un 1, por ejemplo?

Comment: Solo el número, amenadiel. Para coger stderr habría que redirigir 2: `res_stderr="$(comando 2>&1 > /dev/null)"`

Comment: eso es! siempre se me olvida el 2 y al final termino usando un child process de nodejs para hacer exactamente lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas de comprobar si un comando se ejecutó correctamente. Empezaré por los casos simples.

#### 1. Listas AND y OR

Usando los operadores `&&` y `||` es posible encadenar varios comandos que se ejecutarán únicamente si el código de salida del comando anterior es el deseado, lo cual usualmente se traduce a si dicho comando tiene éxito o no. Por ejemplo:

```
cd Documentos && pwd
```

El comando `pwd` se ejecutará solo si el código de salida del comando `cd` es **igual** a 0. Por otro lado:

```
rm archivo || echo 'No se pudo borrar el archivo'
```

El comando `echo` se ejecutará solo si el código de salida del comando `rm` es **distinto** de 0.

Toma en cuenta que estos operadores deben ser usados en listas de comandos y en ningún momento deberían ser usados como atajo a construcciones condicionales más apropiadas. Para muestra, un botón:

```
comando1 && comando2 || comando3
```

Todo parece bien a simple vista. Se ejecuta `comando1` y, dependiendo de si tiene éxito o no, se ejecuta `comando2` o bien `comando3`. El problema es que si `comando1` tiene éxito pero `comando2` falla, entonces `comando3` también será ejecutado:

```
true && false || echo Hola
```

Si esa es tu intención, perfecto. Pero muchas personas esperan un comportamiento similar al operador `?:` del lenguaje C, lo cual nos lleva al siguiente punto.

#### 2. Comando `if`

Tal y como muestra fedorqui en su respuesta, el comando compuesto `if` sirve para hacer construcciones condicionales apropiadas:

```
if comando1; then comando2; else comando3; if
```

Si únicamente te interesa detectar si algún comando falla:

```
if ! comando1; then comando2; fi
```

El signo de exclamación `!` invierte el código de salida de `comando1`, por lo que `comando2` será ejecutado si el primero falla. También puedes aprovechar los `elif` para crear construcciones más complejas.

```
if comando1; then
  comando2
elif comando3; then
  comando4
elif comando5; then
  comando6
else
  comando7
fi
```

#### 3. Parámetro especial `?`

Es importante hacer notar que los dos métodos anteriores lidian con los códigos de salida pero únicamente detectan si son iguales o distintos de 0, son incapaces de lidiar con códigos de salida específicos.

Hay comandos (como `curl`) que usan distintos códigos de salida para diferentes propósitos, por lo que es necesarío cambiar el método para reaccionar correctamente a este tipo de situaciones.

Por fortuna, los intérpretes de comandos compatibles con POSIX (como Bash) permiten acceder al código de salida del último comando ejecutado a través del parámetro especial `?`:

```
$ false; echo "${?}"
1
```

```
$ (exit 12); echo "${?}"
12
```

Ahora podemos hacer construcciones más complejas usando `if` o `case`:

```
comando

# Guardamos el código de salida en una variable
# para poder analizarlo repetidas veces
codigo_de_salida="${?}"

if [ "${codigo_de_salida}" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 'El código de salida es 0'
elif [ "${codigo_de_salida}" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo 'El código de salida es 1'
elif [ "${codigo_de_salida}" -eq 2 ]; then
  echo 'El código de salida es 2'
elif [ "${codigo_de_salida}" -eq 3 ]; then
  echo 'El código de salida es 3'
fi
```

```
comando

case "${?}" in
( 0 ) echo 'El código de salida es 0' ;;
( 1 ) echo 'El código de salida es 1' ;;
( 2 ) echo 'El código de salida es 2' ;;
( 3 ) echo 'El código de salida es 3' ;;
esac
```

#### 4. Información de salida (salida estándar, error estándar, etc.)

Cabe mencionar que hay comandos que, aún si se ejecutan exitosamente, no ofrecen la información que el usuario necesita. Es decir, su ejecución *falla* en el sentido coloquial de la palabra. También puede ocurrir lo contrario, se muestra la información necesaria pero el código de salida es distinto de 0 por alguna razón. En estos casos los códigos de salida no nos son de mucha ayuda.

Para lidiar correctamente con estas situaciones, es necesario analizar la información de salida de dichos programas. Lamentablemente, el método variará dependiendo del comando, pero listaré los 2 más comunes.

Para evitar repetir código, los siguientes ejemplos asumen que la salida del comando está almacenada en la variable `salida`:

```
salida="$(comando)"
```

#### 4.1 Presencia o ausencia de la información de salida

Si el éxito del comando se determina únicamente por la presencia o ausencia de la información de salida, tenemos al menos 2 herramientas que nos ayudarán a detectarla.

La expansión de parámetro `${#parametro}` nos permite conocer la longitud en caracteres del parámetro `parametro`:

```
if [ "${#salida}" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo 'La salida contiene información'
else
  echo 'La salida está vacía'
fi
```

```
if [ "${#salida}" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 'La salida está vacía'
else
  echo 'La salida contiene información'
fi
```

También podemos usar los operandos `-n` y `-z` del comando `test`/`[ ... ]`:

```
if [ -n "${salida}" ]; then
  echo 'La salida contiene información'
else
  echo 'La salida está vacía'
fi
```

```
if [ -z "${salida}" ]; then
  echo 'La salida está vacía'
else
  echo 'La salida contiene información'
fi
```

#### 4.2 Cadenas de texto en la información de salida

Si el éxito del comando se determina por la presencia o ausencia de una cadena de texto en específico (una frase, un código, etc.), entonces es necesario comprobar si dicha cadena aparece en la información de salida.

Por ejemplo, si la cadena es lo único que incluye la información de salida:

```
if [ "${salida}" = "${cadena}" ]; then
  echo 'El comando se ejecutó exitosamente'
else
  echo 'El comando falló en su ejecución'
fi
```

```
case "${salida}" in
( "${cadena}" ) echo 'El comando se ejecutó exitosamente' ;;
( * )           echo 'El comando falló en su ejecución'   ;;
esac
```

Si aparte de la cadena hay más información pero no es necesaria, podemos usar reconocimiento de patrones:

```
# Sintaxis de Bash
if [[ "${salida}" == *"${cadena}"* ]]; then
  echo 'El comando se ejecutó exitosamente'
else
  echo 'El comando falló en su ejecución'
fi
```

```
case "${salida}" in
( *"${cadena}"* ) echo 'El comando se ejecutó exitosamente' ;;
( * )             echo 'El comando falló en su ejecución'   ;;
esac
```

O también expresiones regulares:

```
# Usando grep
if echo "${salida}" | grep "${cadena}"; then
  echo 'El comando se ejecutó exitosamente'
else
  echo 'El comando falló en su ejecución'
fi
```

```
# Sintaxis de Bash, usando grep
if grep "${cadena}" <<< "${salida}"; then
  echo 'El comando se ejecutó exitosamente'
else
  echo 'El comando falló en su ejecución'
fi
```

```
# Sintaxis de Bash
# Es esencial que ${cadena} no esté entre comillas
if [[ "${salida}" =~ ${cadena} ]]; then
  echo 'El comando se ejecutó exitosamente'
else
  echo 'El comando falló en su ejecución'
fi
```

Comment: Fantástica respuesta, muy bien.