# ¿Cómo forsar script de bash cuando un proceso no se ejecuta por el tiempo de la red

Tags: bash, email

estoy creando un script que envie un correo con un backup de la BD,
estoy usuando mutt , y ya me funciona pero debido a la lentitud del
internet el mensaje no se envia y me termina el proceso creandome el backup
pero sin embiarlo

esta es la linea para enviar el correo por mutt y nesesito que cuando no me envie el correo siga intentando este proceso

mutt -s "Copia de seguridad base de datos ${NAME_DB}: $(date +%d) $(date +%m) de $(date +%Y)" ${USER_GMAIL} -a ${NAME}.bz2 < ${DIR}${MESSAGE_FILE}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas saber dentro del script es si `mutt` se ejecuta exitosamente o no.

Para conocer los métodos genéricos que suelen usarse para realizar esto, puedes leer [mi explicación detallada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197021/95447) en la pregunta [¿Cómo consultar en un "if" si un comando se ejecuta sin errores?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/196807/95447).

Aplicándolo a tu caso y asumiendo que `mutt` usa códigos de salida para indicar el estado de la operación, es una tarea sencilla.

Si quieres que el comando se siga ejecutando indefinidamente hasta que tenga éxito:

```
# Usando until
until
  comando
do :; done

# Usando while
while :; do
  if
    comando
  then
    break
  fi
done
```

Si quieres controlar la cantidad de reintentos:

```
reintentos=10

for (( i = 0; i < reintentos; i++ )); do
  if
    comando
  then
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio, muy util el contenido de link