# ¿Cómo puedo controlar un error de ejecución en Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, shell-script

Tengo el siguiente comando:

```
CountRm=`find ${ruta_temporal}/*${cProceso}* -mtime +${vPeriodo} | wc -l`
```

el cual me devuelve el siguiente mensaje al intentar listar el contenido de esa ruta:

```
/usr/bin/find: 0403-027 The parameter list is too long.
```

Ya sé por qué se genera este error y cómo resolverlo, pero mi duda realmente es: ¿cómo puedo capturar el estado de esta ejecucion para mostrarlo en pantalla?

ejemplo:

```
if [ $CountRm <> 0 ];
then
    echo "No se puede realizar el conteo de archivos debido a que son muchos"
else
    echo "termino correctamente el conteo de archivos"
fi
```

si hago un `echo ${CountRm}` no me muestra nada, independientemente de que si puede hacer el conteo o no.

Answer (score 2):

Como una primera aproximación se me ocurre que hagas una especie de área de intercambio temporal. Es decir, un lugar donde guardes el resultado de ciertos comandos para que posteriormente puedas hacer uso de estos.

```
#!/bin/bash

var1() {

    # ls es solo un comando ejemplo, puedes poner tu comando find
    #+siempre y cuando mandes el stderr al archivo temporal "error"
    ls $dir 2> error | wc -l  > count  # "error" y "count" son dos archivos normales
                                       #+que utilizaras como areas de intercambio.

    # Si hay errores, entonces devuelves "-1", de otra manera devuelves el conteo
    #+de las lineas.
    [[ "$(wc -l error | cut -d " " -f 1)" != "0" ]] \
        && echo "-1" \
        || cat count
    rm error count  # Borras los archivos porque no queremos basura.
}

dir="dir1"  # Este directorio si existe.
var1=$(var1)
echo "var1 es $var1"

dir=dir2  # Este directorio no existe.
var1=$(var1)
echo "var1 ahora es $var1"
```

Esta aproximación sólo maneja el "stderr" mas no el estado de salida del primer comando.

Su ejecución arroja algo por el estilo.

```
$ ./variable
var1 es 5
var1 ahora es -1
```

Como segunda aproximación, utilizaré archivos de tipo "pipe" para controlar el flujo de los datos de diversos procesos que utilizaré. De esta manera entran en una mini red de intercomunicación.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -e p_error ]] && rm p_error && mkfifo p_error  #  Reviso si existen esos archivos y los vuelvo
[[ -e p_count ]] && rm p_count && mkfifo p_count  #+ a crear por si tienen algin descriptor abierto 
                                                  #+ esperando algo de algun proceso previo.

[[ -e p_error ]] || mkfifo p_error
[[ -e p_count ]] || mkfifo p_count

var1() {
    #  Ejecuto un subproceso que me va a permitir controlar la salida del stderr de comando "ls"
    #+ (que tu puedes cambiar por otro) hacia otro subproceso que va a comunicar el posible error por
    #+ el pipe p_error, el stdout de "ls" lo voy a procesar con "wc -l" y vor a almacenar ese resultado
    #+ en el otro pipe p_count. Pero como quiero que esto se ejecute en background, para que me permita
    #+ continuar con la ejecucion del programa, utilizo "&"
    bash -c "ls $dir 2> >( wc -l | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > p_error ) | wc -l  > p_count &" 
    #                 |______________________________________|
    #           _________________________|
    #          |
    #          |  Aqui evaluo lo recibido a traves de p_error, es decir, las lineas de error
    #          |  ingresadas a traves de "2> >( wc -l ... p_error )"
    if [[ "$(< p_error)" != "0" ]]  
    then
        #  Si p_error arroja algo diferente de 0, significa que existio un aviso de error
        #+ por parte del comando "ls" y que fue enviado al pipe p_error
        cat p_count > /dev/null  # "Liberamos" al archivo p_count al enviar su resultado
                              #+ a /dev/null. De otra manera el script se queda colgado
                              #+ en el anterior "wc -l  > p_count" y no avanzaria.
        echo "-1"
    else
        cat p_count
    fi
}

dir="dir1"  # Existe y tiene 5 archivos.
var1=$(var1)
echo "var1 es $var1"

dir="dir2"  # No existe.
var1=$(var1)
echo "var1 ahora es $var1"
```

La clave en esta segunda aproximación es utilizar procesos hijos y que estos se comuniquen a través de archivos de tipo pipe.

El resultado de la ejecución de este daría algo semejante al anterior.

```
$ ./variable
var1 es 5
var1 ahora es -1
```

Las primeras dos aproximaciones tratan el mensaje de error, sin embargo, para tratar exclusivamente con el estado de salida usaré la variable propia de BASH `PIPESTATUS` la cual es un array que contiene en cada entrada los estados de salida de cada comando del último *pipeline* ejecutado.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -e p_error ]] && rm p_error && mkfifo p_error
[[ -e p_count ]] && rm p_count && mkfifo p_count

[[ -e p_count ]] || mkfifo p_count
[[ -e p_error ]] || mkfifo p_error

var1() {

    comando="ls $dir"  #  En este caso pondre el comando como una cadena, para mostrar que la ejecucion
                       #+ es independiente del comando. 
    bash -c "$comando 2> /dev/null | wc -l  > p_count; echo \"\${PIPESTATUS[0]}\" > p_error " &
    #                      |                     |                    |_____ En este caso solo quiero el estado
    #                      |                     |                de salida del primer comando y luego lo envio
    #                      |                     |                al archivo pipe p_error.
    #                      |                     |
    #                      |                     |__ El resultado del pipeline lo envio al archivo pipe
    #                      |                      de p_count
    #                      |
    #                      |_ No nos interesa el mensaje de error porque controlaremos
    #                       el proceso a traves de sus estados de salida.

    #  Hasta aqui tenemos el comando anterior ejecutado en un subproceso, pero este comando esta
    #+ en espera para que se reciba el contenido enviado a traves de los archivos p_count y p_error.
    #+ por lo que primero liberamos la parte de p_count para poder dejar que el proceso anterior
    #+ llege a p_error.
    conteo=$(< p_count)  # Almacenamos el conteo de las lineas.

    #  Ahora obtenemos el contenido ingresado en el pipe de p_error, el cual ya se encuentra
    #+ disponible porque dejamos que el primer comando terminara hasta esa parte del pipeline.
    [[ "$(< p_error)" != "0" ]] \
        && echo "-1" \
        || echo $conteo
    #  Recordamos, recibimos -1 si salio algo mal (puedes personalizar tus mensajes segun los estados que
    #+ quieras filtrar) o mostramos conteo.
}

dir="dir1"  # Existe y tiene 5 archivos.
var1=$(var1)
echo "var1 es $var1"

dir="dir2"  # No existe.
var1=$(var1)
echo "var1 ahora es $var1"
```

Como puedes ver, esta última aproximación está muy relacionada con las dos anteriores. La primera es con archivos normales, la segunda es con pipelines pero aun sobre el mensaje del stderr, y la tercera es con pipelines pero con la variable `PIPESTATUS` que es un array con los estados de salida del último pipeline ejecutado.

Y la forma de ejecutar resulta la misma.

```
./variable
var1 es 5
var1 ahora es -1
```

Donde ya puedes actuar según el resultado de `var1`.

Answer (score 1):

yo plantearia otra opcion: la de utilizar la captura de señales en tu script.

se podria hacer algo como:

```
errors()
{
  echo "error detectado"
  exit 1
}
trap errors 6 15

CountRm=`find ${ruta_temporal}/*${cProceso}* -mtime +${vPeriodo} | wc -l`
... # el resto de tu script.
```

la idea es que defines una funcion de error. capturas en tu script las señales 6 y 15 (SIGABRT y SIGTERM) y las diriges a esa funcion. 
Cuando en tu script ocurran esas señales, se lanzara la funcion de error, y ahi controlas lo que necesites mostrar.

NOTA: es un supuesto, no estoy seguro al 100% de si deberias cojer las señales 6 y 15... Echa un vistazo a la tabla de este enlace https://www.shellscript.sh/trap.html para optimizarlo en tu caso.

Comment: Recomiendo usar los nombres de las señales en vez de sus números, ya que algunos de estos varían de acuerdo a la arquitectura tal y como lo indica [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html): _"Several signal numbers are architecture-dependent, as indicated in the 'Value' column."_

Answer (score 1):

En mi respuesta a la pregunta [¿Cómo consultar en un “if” si un comando se ejecuta sin errores?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197021/95447) cubrí un caso similar en el último ejemplo (4.2 Cadenas de texto en la información de salida).

En tu caso, si quieres detectar si la lista de argumentos es muy larga, puedes guardar el mensaje de error para analizarlo posteriormente:

```
CountRm="$(... 2> error.txt)"
MensajeDeError="$(< error.txt)"

if [[ "${MensajeDeError}" == *'The parameter list is too long.' ]]; then
    echo 'No se puede realizar el conteo de archivos debido a que son muchos'
fi
```

Toma en cuenta que para detectar otro tipo de errores necesitarías cambiar el método de detección. Para más información sobre cómo reaccionar correctamente a los tipos de errores más comunes, revisa mi respuesta enlazada arriba.